# show wget stats every a fixed amount of time

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, wget

I would like to see the progress stats of wget every 1 minute. I tried this command but it shows the progress stats every several milliseconds:

```
wget --progress=dot -c http://10.2.2.30/file.dat
```

Comment: Did you try piping it to `pv`?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the watch command
    watch --interval 60 wget ${URL}

Comment: Not what I am looking for. for example, the bandwidth should the average of the used bandwidth in 1 minute. (not just showing the text after 1 minute)